# jQuery if form field's part of value matches values in array, then

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want my email form filed to be validated by jQuery.

if user typed val() matches any values in array, i want to run some function before submitting.

ex.
if I type

`abc.com` is not in array. so OK.

`bbb.net` is in array. so NG.

`username@ccc.co.uk` part of string is in array. so NG.

`blah@aaa.ne.` i do not care... let PHP decide if its valid email. so javascriptly OK.

html:

```
<form action="./" method="post" id="test">
email address: <input type="text" id="mail">

<input type="submit" val="SUBMIT " id="subm">
</form>
```

javascript:

```
var arr = [
'aaa.ne.jp', 'bbb.net', 'ccc.co.uk', 'ddd.co.kr'
];

$('#test').on('submit', function() {
var _value = $('#mail').val();
if( $.inArray(_value, arr) > 0 || _value == '') {
    console.log(_value + '　cant be accepted');
    return false;
} else {
    console.log(_value + ' is GO!');
    return false;//do not submit just for the sake of example.
}
});
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/nori2tae/RgWNM/)

i used jquery's `inArray()` method, but somehow ,for example, `username@ccc.co.uk` gets through the validation even though `ccc.co.uk` is in array.

any solution will be appreciated. thanx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `splitting the email` and compare the latter part  after `@`

```
var arr = [
    'aaa.ne.jp', 'bbb.net', 'ccc.co.uk', 'ddd.co.kr'];

$('#test').on('submit', function () {
    var _value = $('#mail').val();
    if (_value !== '' && _value.indexOf('@') > -1) {
        var parts = _value.split('@');
        if ($.inArray(parts[1], arr) > 0 || _value == '') {
            console.log(_value + '　cant be accepted');
            return false;
        } else {
            console.log(_value + ' is GO!');
            return false; //do not submit just for the sake of example.
        }
    } else {
        console.log(_value + '　cant be accepted');
        return false;
    }
});
```

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/RgWNM/18/)**

Comment: your solution works great! and also this solution simply checkes if its the email address (by checking if it contains @ sign).Thank you very mucho.

Comment: @norixxx..  Glad to have helped :)

Comment: missed one thing... if i type `@aaa.ne.jp`, form gets through. Only first value in array. From second, fine. ie. `@bbb.net`, `blah@bbb.net` or `bbb.net`, cannot get through. What problem can you think of?

Comment: I changed `$.inArray(parts[1], arr) > 0` to `$.inArray(parts[1], arr) > -1` so that first string in array is in handle. :)

Answer (score 0):

The email value you are comparing has more characters that what is needed for the inArray() method to work. It is not a direct comparison.  You could do this. It gets everything after the '@' to compare in $.inArray.

```
$('#test').on('submit', function() {
    var _value = $('#mail').val();
    var _value2 = _value.split("@").pop();
    if( $.inArray(_value2, arr) > 0 || _value2 == '') {
        console.log(_value + '　cant be accepted');
        return false;
    } else {
        console.log(_value + ' is GO!');
        return false;//do not submit just for the sake of example.
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use grep

```
var arr = [
    'aaa.ne.jp', 'bbb.net', 'ccc.co.uk', 'ddd.co.kr'];

$('#test').on('submit', function () {
    var _value = $('#mail').val(),
        _matches = $.grep(arr, function (val, i) { 
                       return _value.indexOf(val) != -1 
                   });

    if (_matches.length > 0) {
        //contains something
    } else {
        console.log(_value + '　cant be accepted');
        return false;
    }
});
```